# Make Bootstrap Columns of the Same Height using flexbox in Safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make columns of same height using bootstrap 3. i am using flex box to do this, it's working fine on chrome and firefox but i am not able to achieve it on safari.

```css
.flex-it {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-it">
  <div class="col-xs-3" style="-webkit-flex-basis:auto; flex-basis: auto;">
    <div class="card">
     <img src='http://worldversus.com/img/zara.jpg' style="width:100%;">
     <div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">
      <span>Lorem</span>
     </div>
     <div style="font-size: 12px;">
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3" style="-webkit-flex-basis:auto; flex-basis: auto;">
    <div class="card">
     <img src='http://worldversus.com/img/zara.jpg' style="width:100%;">
     <div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">
      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
     </div>
     <div style="font-size: 12px;">
      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Can someone please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
       <div class="panel-heading">Test </div>
       <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Test Test Test </div>
       <div class="panel-footer">Test Test </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well"> 
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well"> 
       Test Test Test Test 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well"> 
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
     Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test  
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:0;
}

.row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
     margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}

.container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div,.row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
    width:100%;
}


.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.flex-grow {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
}
.card{
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);

}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

Please check in safari browser working fine
Bootstrap v3.1.1

I have updated , so update html code and css code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
                    <img src='http://worldversus.com/img/zara.jpg' style="width:100%;">
                    <div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">
                        <span>Lorem</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
                    <img src='http://worldversus.com/img/zara.jpg' style="width:100%;">
                    <div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">
                        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>

  </div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicity declaring the [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) property:

```
.row > [class*='col-'] {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

This could cause issues with responsiveness, however. If so try removing the `flex-wrap` properties from `.flex-it` and adding the below code instead:

```
.row {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display:         flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Default behavior of browser and can't be change. So you have to do some trick like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* Get browser */
    $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    /* Detect Chrome */
    if($.browser.chrome){

        /* Finally, if it is Chrome then jQuery thinks it's 
           Safari so we have to tell it isn't */
        $.browser.safari = false;
    }

    /* Detect Safari */
    if($.browser.safari){
        /* Do something for Safari */
        $('.container').addClass("Safari");//Adding class in parent div safari if browser is safari
    }

});
```

Now you can customize your style like this

```
.Safari .card{
//do your custom style here
}
```

Comment: If you feel difficult to do this, I can do it for you